# How can i display post loop in table format?

Tags: php, plugin-development, loop

I am creating a comparison table and the issue is in while loop i am not able to put the `"tr"` in proper place.  I need layout like this

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>post title 1</td>
<td>post title 2</td>
<td>post title 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>post content 1</td>
<td>post content 2</td>
<td>post content 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>post author 1</td>
<td>post author 2</td>
<td>post author 3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How can i achieve that it's seems like no option see my code below

```
<div class="acadp">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <?php while( $acadp_query->have_posts() ) : $acadp_query->the_post();  ?>
        <td><?php the_title(); ?></td>
         <td><?php the_content(); ?></td>
        <td><?php the_author(); ?></td>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <tr>

 </table>
</div>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="acadp">
<?php 
$compare =[];
while( $acadp_query->have_posts() ) {
    $acadp_query->the_post(); $post_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID ); 
    $category = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'acadp_categories' ); 
    $compare['Title'][] = get_the_title();
    $compare['Manufacturer'][] =  $category[0]->name; 

    $compare['Image'][] = get_the_acadp_listing_thumbnail($post_meta);


    if( count( $fields ) ){
        foreach( $fields as $field ) {
            $value = $post_meta[ $field->ID ][0];
            $compare[$field->post_title][] =  $value;
        }
    }

    $compare['URL'][] = "<a href='".get_the_permalink()."' class='btn btn-primary'>View Details</a>";
}

?>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<?php foreach ($compare as $feature => $value): ?>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $feature; ?></th>
        <td><?php echo implode("</td><td>",$value); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
</div>
<!-- end of the loop -->

<!-- Use reset postdata to restore orginal query -->
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need 3 separate loops. One for each row, with each post creating a new column:

```
<div class="acadp">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <?php while( $acadp_query->have_posts() ) : $acadp_query->the_post();  ?>
                <td><?php the_title(); ?></td>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <?php while( $acadp_query->have_posts() ) : $acadp_query->the_post();  ?>
                <td><?php the_content(); ?></td>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <?php while( $acadp_query->have_posts() ) : $acadp_query->the_post();  ?>
                <td><?php the_author(); ?></td>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: this is just an example actually i have meta data... and that can be multiple rows... using multiple loops isn't an option there..

Comment: Well too bad, because it's the only way. Use a separate loop to loop over the meta keys for each row, but within those rows you'll need to use another loop for the posts.

Comment: is there any option i, i can get the total number of rows.. is there any way i can do this in a single loop? using multiple loops is not going to efficient...

Comment: Why isn't it efficient? You're not doing multiple queries, just multiple loops through the results.

Comment: @TajKhan Jacob is right, it is just as efficient, all the querying happened once and rewinding the loop back doesn't introduce a new query.

Comment: @JacobPeattie shouldn't there be a call to rewind posts inbetween the loops?

Comment: @TomJNowell Nope. `have_posts()` calls `rewind_posts()` if the current post is past the end, which it will be if the loop has previously been completed.

Comment: that's cool.. it actually solves part of my problem, as i discussed i have a for each loop inside my while loop and for custom post meta how can i get around that?

Comment: see updated question

Comment: deleted my answer because @JacobPeattie needs all the attention. There ya go buddy.

Comment: @Ovidiu Mate get over yourself. You gave an answer that made incorrect assertions about how certain functions worked and I pointed them out so you had a tantrum.

Comment: my updated question is not visible ... i have meta data e.g. price,weight,height.. which i retrieve from $post_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID ); and i need to loop through it also.. how's that possible as now i cannot do while loop ?

Comment: whatever you say @JacobPeattie

Comment: Guy's i agree with @Ovidiu here as now with a single while loop i am able to achieve this .. see my answer..

Comment: You’re still doing multiple loops, like I said you’d need to. There’s no meaningful difference between while and foreach. If anything your solution is less efficient because you’re creating new variables with duplicate data.

Comment: I agree but that's the only solution.. as you can see the i have fields as post meta.. and it cannot be achieved using only while loop.. you have better experience but as per your suggestion i may have to write at least 20 while loop.. so according to me this is the more efficient solution.. can we achive the same with only while loop? i tried and failed multiple times..

Answer (score 0):

In stead of echoing author, title and so on during the loop you can also store them in arrays. Then after the loop you can echo every array as a row in your table.

Comment: yes that's what i did..